# Delete email addresses in .csv that are listed in a .txt file

Tags: grep

I run the following command to keep email addresses listed in `emails.txt`

```
grep -wFf emails.txt file.csv > newfile.csv
```

But how would I change this command to remove addresses from `file.csv` that are listed in `emails.txt`

Comment: By "email", do you mean *email address*?

Comment: Yes - Email addresses

Comment: You should mention it, I read it like you were listing actual emails in the `emails.txt` file and that you were keeping your emails in a `csv` file.

Comment: Can you provide a short example for each file? Probably you can use `sort  | uniq` or `sort -u`.

Comment: The `-v` flag to grep inverts the match and may do what you want here

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '!/@/' emails.txt > temp && mv temp emails.csv
```

Beware that this will delete all lines with an instance of @ in them. Back up your file perhaps first.

```
cp emails.txt "emails-`date`.txt" 
awk '!/@/' emails.txt > temp && mv temp emails.csv
```

Example:

```
$ cat emails.txt 
aaa
bbb
mick@gmail.com
ccc
dave@hotmail.com

$ awk '!/@/' emails.txt > temp && mv temp emails.csv

$ cat emails.csv 
aaa
bbb
ccc
```